Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'serialport.dll': The specified module could not be found
I want to create the desktop application for reading the USB port, read the data of the USB, perform some operation and
trying to use the package flutter_libserialport 0.4.0. for fetching the serial port.
But got the error:  Failed to load dynamic library 'serialport.dll': The specified module could not be found.I searched for the solution and I found the issue discussed here but no avail.
https://github.com/jpnurmi/libserialport.dart/issues/48 .
Here, it is said that this package already handle it.
For the instance, I used the same code from the docs.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport/example
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_libserialport/flutter_libserialport.dart';

void main() => runApp(ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleAppState createState() => _ExampleAppState();
}

extension IntToString on int {
  String toHex() => '0x${toRadixString(16)}';
  String toPadded([int width = 3]) => toString().padLeft(width, '0');
  String toTransport() {
    switch (this) {
      case SerialPortTransport.usb:
        return 'USB';
      case SerialPortTransport.bluetooth:
        return 'Bluetooth';
      case SerialPortTransport.native:
        return 'Native';
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
  var availablePorts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPorts();
  }

  void initPorts() {
    setState(() => availablePorts = SerialPort.availablePorts);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Serial Port example'),
        ),
        body: Scrollbar(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              for (final address in availablePorts)
                Builder(builder: (context) {
                  final port = SerialPort(address);
                  return ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text(address),
                    children: [
                      CardListTile('Description', port.description),
                      CardListTile('Transport', port.transport.toTransport()),
                      CardListTile('USB Bus', port.busNumber?.toPadded()),
                      CardListTile('USB Device', port.deviceNumber?.toPadded()),
                      CardListTile('Vendor ID', port.vendorId?.toHex()),
                      CardListTile('Product ID', port.productId?.toHex()),
                      CardListTile('Manufacturer', port.manufacturer),
                      CardListTile('Product Name', port.productName),
                      CardListTile('Serial Number', port.serialNumber),
                      CardListTile('MAC Address', port.macAddress),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: initPorts,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String? value;

  CardListTile(this.name, this.value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(value ?? 'N/A'),
        subtitle: Text(name),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Any help would be really appreciated!!!
